# MVC how to pass two input text in action parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameters, action

please I have a problem with the parameters of an action. Can someone help me? I'll explain:

I have an action "Etiquette (string nom_pharm, int numBon, int nbColis)" in the "Etiquetage" controller. In the view I have two input text for numBon and nbColis, I try to get them back to pass them in parameter but always the second one indicates that it is null, I use this line:

```
<input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Etiquette", "Etiquetage",new { nom_pharm = @Model.PharmacieNom, numBon = " ", nbColis = " " })'+parseInt(document.getElementById('in').value), +parseInt(document.getElementById('bon').value)" />
```

Do you have an idea of the correct syntax?

Comment: In your question please show types for `Etiquette` method parameters. You're assigning empty string to `numBon` on that code. What do you expect to get?

Comment: Yes sorry , Etiquette (string nom_pharm,int numBon, int nbColis)

Answer (score 1):

The relative url you need is /Etiquetage/Etiquette?non_pharm={value of in}&numBon={value of bon}&nbColis={value of in}
but your code is generating this /Etiquetage/Etiquette?non_pharm={value}&numBon= &nbColis= {value of in}{value of bon}.

Your approach is a bit strange. A more conventional approach would be to use a form with a POST rather than a GET.  Assumming you have a good reason for using javascript here for sending a GET request this code should work.

```
<input type="button"
   value="Ok"
   onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Etiquette", "Etiquetage")?non_pharm=@Model.PharmacieNom&numBon='
                                        + document.getElementById('bon').value + '&nbColis='
                                        + document.getElementById('in').value" />
```

Note I have assumed that 'bon' goes with numBon and 'in' goes with nbColis.
Because you are creating a string the parseInts are not needed.